# Replace mysql data when printing to text

Tags: php, mysql

Currently when someone loggs out of a game it goes into the database with there game mode

```
modes:
0 = easy
1 = noive
2 = legendary
```

on my highscores for modes im trying to get it to replace
 "0" to "easy" "1" to say novice and ofc "2" to say legendary

[image]

My code:

```
$skill_xp = strtolower($skill.'_xp');
$min = $page == 1 ? 0 : ($page * 25) - 25;
$res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM hs_users ORDER BY $skill_xp DESC LIMIT $min, 25");
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    $rank = ($page * 25) - 24;
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $level = $skill_xp == 'overall_xp' ? getTotalLevel($row, $skills) : getLevelForXp($row[$skill_xp], $skill);
        echo '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$rank.'</td>
            <td><a href="?player='.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a></td>
            <td><a href="?player='.$row['difficulty'].'">'.$row['difficulty'].'</a></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">'.getLevel($row).'</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">'.number_format($level).'</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">'.number_format($row[$skill_xp]).'</td>
            </tr>';
        $rank++;
    }
}
```

Comment: if($myVar == 0){print 'Easy';) or you can do it directly from the query with a decode maybe

Comment: I added this and does not help im affraid , just puts easyeasyeasyeasy everywhere :  http://prntscr.com/5hgnsn

Comment: You need print modes in human readable format exactly in SQL? I mean without using PHP?

Comment: @DanHammond you can use elseif, add other if ($myvar == 1) example, or use switch as ole suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switch` for this.

Create a function like so:

```
function translateSkill( $skill ){
switch( $skill ){
    case 0:
    return "Easy";
    break;
    case 1: 
    return "Novice";
    break;
    case 2:
    return "Legen ... wait for it ... DARY!";
    break;
}
}
```

and in your `<td>` instead of:

```
<td><a href="?player='.$row['difficulty'].'">'.$row['difficulty'].'</a></td>
```

you use:

```
<td><a href="?player='.$row['difficulty'].'">'.translateSkill( $row['difficulty'] ).'</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an array with all available mode. (If the `$row['difficulty']` store the values)

```
$mode = array(
    0 => 'easy',
    1 => 'novice',
    2 => 'legendary'
);
```

Then later, you can access that array by array key:

```
echo '<td><a href="?player='.$row['difficulty'].'">'.$mode[$row['difficulty']].'</a></td>';
```